# On ruby, why include is private and extend is public?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, language-design, access-specifier

On ruby, what is the reason for `include` is private, while `Object#extend` is public?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Object#extend` *has* to be public, otherwise you wouldn't be able to use it. After all, its purpose is to mix in a module into an object, so you'd generally call it like `obj.extend(Foo)`, which isn't possible with private methods.

`Module#include` is usually only used inside a module body like so:

```
class Bar
  include Foo
end
```

I.e. it is usually called without a receiver, so it doesn't have to be public. Of course, it doesn't *have* to be private either.

My guess is the reason why it is private is that it is more invasive, because it changes the behavior of *every* instance of `Bar`, whereas `Object#extend` only changes a single object. Therefore, `Module#include` is in some sense "more dangerous" and thus is made private.

I don't know whether that is the actual reason, but it is consistent with other similar methods like `Module#define_method`.

Comment: It doesn't *have* to be. You would be able to use it if it was private: `obj.send(:extend, Foo)`, `obj.instance_eval{ extend Foo }`, not including the case for modules `class Bar; extend Foo; end`

Comment: @Marc-AndréLafortune: Or `class << obj; extend Foo; end`, of course. Like I said, it's just a guess.

Comment: I was replying to your first sentence "`Object#extend` has to be public, otherwise you wouldn't be able to use it."

Comment: PS: I can't think of a single circumstance where one would do `class << obj; extend Foo; end`, as in your comment.

Comment: Fast-forward to 2014. `Module#include` (and `Module#prepend`) were made public in v2.1.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to run `Foo.include(Bar)` at any point would most likely be a source of very nasty bugs.

Answer (score 1):

To supplement Jörg W Mittag's answer, Object#extend can also be used to include module's instance methods to be used in the class level (which will also be available to all instances of that class):

```
module Foo
  def bar (baz)
  end
end

class Qux
  extend Foo

  bar 'asdf'
end
```